# Запрос записей, для которых нет связей в другой связанной таблице

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Есть две таблицы

```
class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table1"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String, nullable=False)

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table2"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String, nullable=False)
    table1_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, ForeignKey('table1.id'))
```

Как написать запрос, который вернет все записи из таблицы Table1, при условии, что в таблице Table2 не найдётся, среди имеющихся записей, ни одной, которая бы ссылалась по связи Table1.id=Table2.table1_id

Что-то похожее:

```
if Table1.id not in Table2.table1_id.list:
    print(Table1.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
db_session.query(
    Table1
).filter(
    ~Table1.id.in_(
        query(
            Table2.table1_id
        )
    )
)
```